# How can an EL expression be embedded in an HTML string that is generated by jquery/javascript for insertion into a JSP page)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

How can an EL expression be embedded in an HTML string that is generated by jQuery/JavaScript for insertion into a JSP page)?

For example, I've tried something the following:

```
$("#div01").after("<h4>${sessionScope}</h4>");
```

...but, the EL expression -- i.e.,  `${sessionScope}` -- does **not** get evaluated.

Comment: You could send expression to the server for evaluation and return back as a result.

Comment: How would that work, Roman?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't, at least not the normal way...  JSP is compiled and executed on the server and the page contents are sent to the browser.  The browser then executes any JavaScript after receiving the page.  By then, it's too late to have the JSP recompiled...

Instead, send the value along with the page, perhaps in a hidden input field.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Steve.  Not the answer I wanted (I was hoping there was a way), but, indeed the answer I sort of expected.

Answer (score 1):

Call a function from a script tag and pass the value from there:

JS:

```
function paste(str) {
  $("#div01").after("<h4>" + str + "</h4>");
}
```

JSP:

```
<script src="js/script-containing-paste.js"></script>
<script>paste(${sessionScope.myStr});</script>
```